# How to search images using Json in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, url

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDochCep4-pyP_VyC-yTxqvVXz2oUccvOQ&cx=015184184090674442837:dkitjh1tmc8&q=";         
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.globalWordName]; //appdelegate.globalwordname is required images name           
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&searchType=image&safe=high&imgSize=medium&start=1&num=10&alt=json"];
```

(or)

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBfsopy4kXXiZ44BRUE1pVMyacSUa0Bn1E&cx=cx=011683172338421882045:tcle_wvfko8&q=";
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.globalWordName];
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&searchType=image&safe=high&imgSize=medium&start=1&num=10&alt=json"];
```

(or)

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=";
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.globalWordName];  
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&rsz=8"];
```

I am using the above three formats but i didn't get any result. It returns just null after executing the above queries. Please help me any one what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that API key (key=?) and Custom search engine ID (cx=?) are correct.